# Exponential search worst-case performance

Tags: binary-search

I'm learning about Exponential search and I keep reading that the worst-case performance is $\log_2 i$ where $i$ is the searched index.

I tried with an array containing $1073741824$ elements ($1024\cdot1024\cdot1024$) and I searched for the $1073741823$th element (which is just $n-1$).

Therefore, I used the exponential search to get the range containing $i$ (which was $[536870912, 1073741824]$) and it took $\log_2 n$ to find. Then it took another $\log_2(n/2)$ to find the right index using Binary search in this range only.

Am I doing something wrong? Or is the complexity of the worst-case $2\log_2 n-1$ ?

Comment: They probably meant that the worst case performance is $\Theta(\log i)$.

Comment: Another possibility is that $\log_2 i$ bounds the number of iterations (or comparisons) until you find a range containing $i$, and before performing binary search.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Ah yes! This is probably it.